# How to apply options set in /etc/default/* without rebooting the system?

Tags: debian

I always ignored this problem because I was able to restart the system, but this time a reboot is not possible.

For some applications I edit the configs partially in /etc/default/* (at least on debian), like openvpn or snmp.

This time I want to change the start parameters from snmp, so I edit the file /etc/default/snmpd but what I change there does not apply when I restart snmpd, only when I reboot the whole system.

Is there any workaround for this problem?

Comment: Putting your OS version might be critical here, because starting from Debian 8.0 init system has been changed to systemd by default. And how do you restart your service exactly (command)?

Comment: What the particular option you are changing in `/etc/default/snmpd` which requires system reboot?

Comment: Debian 9.1, I restart with service snmpd restart OR /etc/init.d/snmpd restart OR systemctl restart snmpd.service
@Khaled I edit the parameter "SNMPDOPTS=" to change verbosity level

Comment: And yes the new init system seems to be the problem, on debian 8 it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

`/lib/systemd/system/snmpd.service` replaced `/etc/default/snmpd` in debian 9 because of systemd